# Redirect depending on URI Segment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and want to have SEO-friendly URLs. There will be 2 types of URI segments, `http://www.domain.com/view/193847` and `http://www.domain.com/view/193847-canon-5d-mark-iii`.

If the first URL is used, function `view_mini` is called and passed the product id `193847`. If the 2nd one is used, function `view_full` will be called and passed the same product id `193847`.

**Problem:** How can I differentiate between the 2 URLs? Or is this an inferior approach to solve the problem?

**PHP** *How should the if condition be structured?*

```
function view($pid) {
    if($this->uri->segment(2) == something) {
        $this->view_mini($pid);
    } else {
        $this->view_full($pid);
        }
}

function view_mini($pid) {
   // ...
}

function view_full($pid) {
   // ...
}
```

**EDIT**

I am using URL routing to route `http://www.domain.com/controllername/view/1234` to `http://www.domain.com/view/1234`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the regular expression to check the segment if it has anything other than numbers, then you can execute the view that you want for example

```
$pattern = '\d[0-9][^a-zA-Z]';
$url = $this->uri->segment(2);
if(preg_match($pattern,$url))
{
//this will match only the numbers

$this->view_mini($pid);
    } else {
        $this->view_full($pid);
    }
```

i hope this will help ..

Comment: This pattern should also help " /(\d+)-([a-zA-Z]*)?/g "

Comment: @Philip thats absolutely right .. your patter will search for the full url mine will search for the numbers only .. both work .. thanks

Comment: I think I would prefer to check if any characters or hyphen exist in the uri segment rather than search for numeric values as numeric values should appear in both url queries.

Comment: my patter will only search for the first numbers which is the first part of the URI , you can test it here http://gskinner.com/RegExr .. but its a personal favor to do whats best for you ..

Comment: yep that works fine for matching the first set of numbers but the conditional should be based on the next part of the uri segment.  have a look at the two urls the OP posted.  This pattern checks if hyphens and chars exist in the segment. cheers. http://regexr.com?30qjq

Comment: to be honest i didnt look at the if statement .. my concern was to solve the segment part ..

Answer (score 0):

### Edit: un-tested

```
$route["view/(\d+)"] = "class/view_mini/$1";
$route["view/(\d+)-([\w'-]*)?/g"] = "class/view_full/$1/$2";
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the url routing without breaking into proper segments?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any definitive structure to the different URLs?

ie.

```
http://www.domain.com/view/[numbers]-[text]
```

If so, you could test the URL for that dash between the numbers and the dash?

Comment: Yes that is the structure that I want. Sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$result = explode('-', $this->uri->segment(1));

If(isset($result[1]))
{
    // show full view
} else {

    // show mini view

}
```

$pid will always be $result[0]